# nginx is installed but command not found

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, matrix, matrix-synapse

so i'm trying to install matrix synapse on ubuntu. i followed [these](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-matrix-synapse-on-ubuntu-1804/) steps

i wrote all the commands just fine until "the step for Activate the virtual host file and test the configuration." 
Now when i write this Command

```
nginx -t
```

i face with this Error :

bash:: command not found

i  checked that nginx is installed or not but apparently it is installed . But the Commands are somehow unknown for ubuntu ! Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: did you check than nginx is in the path? ```echo $PATH```

Answer (score 1):

If nginx is in path /usr/sbin/ then just try this command:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin/:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

first check the location of the installed nginx executable
if you installed with apt then it should be in `/usr/sbin/`
check that your path contain this directory. if it doesnt, type in this command

`PATH=$PATH:~/usr/sbin`

Comment: i did check    /usr/sbin/    and nginx is installed there .